# How could I render mathematical expressions using Kivy?

Tags: math, rendering, calculator, kivy

I am in the process of making a calculator using Kivy and wanted to do something that resembles the natural textbook display found in a few Casio calculators (http://www.casio-intl.com/asia-mea/en/calc/scientific/ntd/). There's another program which supports such display (http://algebrator.software.informer.com/).

So basically the user inputs the expression and the output of the expression should resemble the 'natural textbook' display. What's the best way to integrate this into my Kivy program? Are there libraries that I could use for this?

I remember one of my friends used LaTeX in Python to display such expressions but I think those were just images.

Comment: Start working on it, and ask question when you are stuck. No Homeworks :)

Comment: I've already made the calculator but it's not yet capable of displaying expressions in a natural way and I have not idea on converting those expressions and displaying them on the calculator in the format I want. So a push in the direction will be of help

Comment: Could be better to ask this on programmers.stackexchange

Comment: @Seki - No, it would not. Programmers is for whiteboard-level questions, not general programming ones.

Comment: When I was working on this about a year back, I ended up making it a server-client system and generated images on the serverside (Django) to display on the clientside.  Needless to say, that did not work very well.

Comment: I found a calculator app on android which uses http://www.reduce-algebra.com/ to render the expression. I'll explore this a bit, though I doubt I'll go far seeing that I have very limited programming experience

Answer (score 1):

Since kivy has an RST renderer, i dug a little in this direction, but seems that only get back to latex, just making things a little easier (maybe). http://svn.python.org/projects/doctools/trunk/doc/ext/math.rst